# Change link colours on Plotly Sankey based on conditions

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, sankey-diagram

does anyone know how to change the colours of the links in a Sankey chart from grey to different colours based on their value?

Say I have this code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
source = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
target = [2, 3, 4, 5, 4]
value  = [8, 2, 2, 8, 4]

link   = dict(source = source, target = target, value = value)
data   = go.Sankey(link = link)
fig    = go.Figure(data)
fig.show()
```

and I want to make links from source to target a specific colour as follows:

- red if the value is 2;
- yellow if the value is 4;
- green if the value is 8

Any help would be much appreciated!

---

**ANSWER**

The answer was a lot simpler than I thought:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
source = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
target = [2, 3, 4, 5, 4]
value  = [8, 2, 2, 8, 4]
color  = ['green', 'red', 'red', 'green', 'yellow']

link   = dict(source = source, target = target, value = value, color = color)
data   = go.Sankey(link = link)
fig    = go.Figure(data)
fig.show()
```

[image]